# Check if all column values in current row is lesser than previous row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to check if all the column values in the current row is less than the corresponding column values in previous row in a pandas dataframe (throughout entire dataframe) and create a new column with a value of 1 or 0 accoringly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

          A         B         C         D
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239
1  0.462691  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744
2  0.777962  0.757983  0.934829  0.831104
3  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535  0.117642
4  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
5  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823  0.836997
6  0.739635  0.866059  0.691271  0.377185
7  0.225146  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946
8  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566  0.900749
9  0.764869  0.253200  0.548054  0.778883
```

**Option 1**
*`shift`*

```
df.assign(New=(df < df.shift()).all(1).astype(int))

          A         B         C         D  New
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239    0
1  0.462691  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744    0
2  0.777962  0.757983  0.934829  0.831104    0
3  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535  0.117642    0
4  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702    1
5  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823  0.836997    0
6  0.739635  0.866059  0.691271  0.377185    0
7  0.225146  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946    0
8  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566  0.900749    0
9  0.764869  0.253200  0.548054  0.778883    0
```

---

**Option 2**
*`numpy`*
Same concept as Option 1

```
v = df.values
df.assign(New=np.append(False, (v[1:] < v[:-1]).all(1).astype(int)))

          A         B         C         D  New
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239    0
1  0.462691  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744    0
2  0.777962  0.757983  0.934829  0.831104    0
3  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535  0.117642    0
4  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702    1
5  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823  0.836997    0
6  0.739635  0.866059  0.691271  0.377185    0
7  0.225146  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946    0
8  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566  0.900749    0
9  0.764869  0.253200  0.548054  0.778883    0
```

**Option 3**
*`diff`*
Use `diff` to compare one row with the next and see if it is less than zero.  Then use `all` to determine if its `True` for the entire row.

```
df.assign(New=df.diff().lt(0).all(1).astype(int))

          A         B         C         D  New
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239    0
1  0.462691  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744    0
2  0.777962  0.757983  0.934829  0.831104    0
3  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535  0.117642    0
4  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702    1
5  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823  0.836997    0
6  0.739635  0.866059  0.691271  0.377185    0
7  0.225146  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946    0
8  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566  0.900749    0
9  0.764869  0.253200  0.548054  0.778883    0
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.assign(New=df.diff().lt(0).all(1).astype(int))
%timeit df.assign(New=(df < df.shift()).all(1).astype(int))

1000 loops, best of 3: 579 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop

%%timeit
v = df.values
df.assign(New=np.append(False, (v[1:] < v[:-1]).all(1).astype(int)))

1000 loops, best of 3: 322 µs per loop
```

---

**How `diff` Works**

> check if all the column values in the current row is less than the corresponding column values in previous row

This is what prompted me to use `diff`.  [**`pandas.DataFrame.diff`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) by default calculates the diff array for every column.  Meaning, for each row, we have the difference of that row relative to the previous row.  For the condition the OP presented to be `True`, we need this difference to be less than zero.

```
df.diff()

          A         B         C         D
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  0.017752 -0.391009  0.390297  0.352505
2  0.315271  0.741438  0.084384  0.013360
3  0.101929  0.168895 -0.213294 -0.713463
4 -0.733985 -0.727035 -0.283971 -0.016940
5  0.132829  0.410018 -0.351741  0.736296
6  0.460900  0.256197  0.605448 -0.459812
7 -0.514489 -0.430779  0.009629  0.323761
8  0.571340 -0.416592 -0.000334  0.199803
9 -0.031618  0.234512 -0.152512 -0.121866
```

Then

```
df.diff() < 0

       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True   True
4   True   True   True   True
5  False  False   True  False
6  False  False  False   True
7   True   True  False  False
8  False   True   True  False
9   True  False   True   True
```

Then

```
(df.diff() < 0).all(1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I didn't get it! Why are we checking for less than zero?

Comment: I need something like this. I need to check the current row. If every column in current row is less than corresponding column values in precious row, I need a '1' in the new column. Else a '0'

Comment: Column 1 Column 2 Output
20 40 NULL
30 80 1
40 20 0

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Thanks! Further extending this, in case I need to check if in the current row, all columns of current row are less than previous corresponding columns (all previous rows appearing before current row), is it possible? The difference is that earlier only the previous row was considered to check,now I want all previous rows to be considered. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Harikrishna that would make a perfect new question.

Comment: unable to post one for 90 mins!

Comment: Quick question! This works good but I need a small alteration. I want this checking to be done from column 3 to the end but ignore the data in column 2. Because column 2 has the date and should be ignored for this logic.Thanks!

Comment: @Harikrishna you can easily alter this logic by subsetting the dataframe with `df.assign(New=df[mycols].diff().lt(0).all(1).astype(int))` where `mycols` is a list of the columns you care to evaluate for this purpose.  Or you can limit the columns by position with `iloc` to restrict it from the 2nd column onward with `df.assign(New=df.iloc[:, 1:].diff().lt(0).all(1).astype(int))`